# Getting error while trying to install Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, cordova, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to install the Facebook SDK for Android  in Eclipse but I'm failing miserably.Eventually my aim is to develop a web app in phonegap and I know I have to get the phonegap plugin for that once I sort out the SDK. But Im failing at the very beginning.

I'm sure I followed all the steps that was laid out in the FacebookSDK-Android guide.Im attaching screen shot of the errors I'm getting to give you guys a better picture.I'm completely new to Android, any help much appreciated.Thanks

https://vimeo.com/69957972

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnK4O.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/etxPh.png

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Im am getting the same error just as yours, I tried all the methods you mention here.

Same screens I was getting.

The soultion I got is:

You need to **create a new clean workspace** before importing the facebook SDK

Goto **File>>Switch Workspace**

When you enter a new path for your workspace, Now import the Facebook SDK and MUST clean the projects as:

**Project>>clean**

There will be no problems at all. I am now running my applications in my device too without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned that you follow the official installation guide for the Facebook SDK, but I provided a link just in case:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

When I read the guide, my eye caught onto something which might prove to be the source of the error which you experience:

*You must unselect the 'Copy projects into workspace' option so that each of the sample projects retains a correct reference to the neighboring SDK. However, this means that Eclipse creates a link to the project in the SDK installation, rather than making a copy of it.*

Please let me know whether or not this helps.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, 'Copy projects into workspace' option was unselected.I tried importing just the Facbook SDK folder but I keep getting these errors http://i.imgur.com/vUtoaSE.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Right click on the project in the Package Explorer.
- Select Android tools->Add support library
- Select the latest support library (current rev 13)
- Accept License and press install

For the example projects. Check that the path to the library 'facebook.jar' is correct

- Right click on the project in the Package Explorer.
- Select Properties
- Select Java Build Path
- Select Libraries
- Check that the 'facebook.jar' path is correct

Comment: Thanks mate but that didnt work either, still getting the same set of errors.Have you installed Facebook SDK for Android in Eclipse before?If you have could you please point to me a guide or something?

Comment: I have but I didn't get this error. You might try to do this: Right click on project->Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export. Make sure that Android Private Libraries and Android Dependencies are checked.

Comment: I tried that as well, could you please check this screenshot? I just need to make sure im doing the right thing : http://i.imgur.com/wvfGfdB.png

Comment: Well, you shouldn't have to expose every library but if it still doesn't work then it something else.

Comment: I just imported one of the example projects and followed the steps like you mentioned.The facebooksdk.jar seems to be missing http://i.imgur.com/nV4FrqN.png

Comment: I have uploaded a video to show the errors I'm getting https://vimeo.com/69957972 .Could you please check and let me know?

Comment: Love the video approach ! Unfortunately, I can't quite make it out. Just to focus on the v4 support lib issue for a minute: when you click on the libs folder in your project do you see android-support-v4.jar ? Have you cleaned your project since doing this ? If so and the error persists, closing down and restarting Eclipse is sometimes required.